# Please convert [tag:conversion]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) is a bit of an oddball. Its description is "This tag indicates that the challenge involves converting from one format to another", which is extremely vague, and could apply to a substantial proportion of all the challenges on this site. As it stands, it seems to encompass everything that could vaguely be considered transforming an input from one format to another, including:

- [Various](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150250/hsl-to-rgb-values) [color](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129208/convert-cmyk-values-to-rgb) [formatting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129055/how-to-convert-hex2-to-rgba) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/from-rgb-to-cmyk)
- [A few](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44830/string-to-binary) [base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35498/implement-atoi-function) [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/200863/convert-a-decimal-integer-to-binary-only-using-arithmetic-operators) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92120/convert-to-bibi-binary), despite [base-conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/base-conversion) existing
- [A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238462/convert-superscript-numbers-to-normal-numbers) [lot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92471/convert-to-bubble-letters) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60443/s%e1%b4%8d%e1%b4%80%ca%9f%ca%9f-c%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%98%ea%9c%b1-c%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%a0%e1%b4%87%ca%80%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%87%ca%80) [character](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57462/goodness-its-covered-in-tabs) [substitution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/my-god-its-full-of-spaces) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101374/line-ending-conversion-program)
- [Some](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252936/convert-an-integer-to-ieee-754-float) [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196003/convert-complex-chinese-numbers-into-arabic-numbers) [format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193357/convert-a-string-of-digits-from-words-to-an-integer) [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170544/count-like-a-babylonian) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176371/densely-packed-decimal-dpd-to-decimal)
- [A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167962/cobol-y2k-redux) [couple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176647/convert-an-excel-date-code-to-a-date) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105858/12-hour-to-24-hour-time-converter) [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/96121/world-time-conversion)/[time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71203/convert-the-time-to-a-string) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65106/running-length-of-the-movie-in-a-human-readable-format)
- [Various](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51109/translate-your-english-source-code-into-a-foreign-language) [miscellaneous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123141/generate-chord-charts-for-ukulele) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129018/how-much-mana-do-i-need)

This tag doesn't really seem to have any consistent meaning more specific than "conversion",  and seems to be somewhat of a meta-tag in that it's blindly applied to most challenges with "convert"/"conversion" in the title/body.

I can think of three possible options for this:

- Narrow [conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion)'s scope down to something more objective, and remove it from a large amount of questions
- Remove it entirely
- Give up and apply it to a third of all [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenges.

So, what should we do with this tag?